# Invoking Grandparent constructor with templated inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++11, variadic-templates

I've chosen to use templated inheritance in order to avoid muliple and virtual inheritance. My goal is to make various children (4 or 5 generations or inheritance that I don't control) have a common function call regardless of what they derive.

My solution is inserting a template inheritance as so:

```
template <typename BASE>
class common_call : public BASE {
public:
    void foo() { /*implementation independent of base*/ }
};

class child1 : public common_call <base1> {};
class child2 : public common_call <base2> {};
```

This has the problem of invoking the constructor of base. Classes base1 and base2 (not written by me) have different constructors that I must invoke in the initialization list. The common_call template knows nothing about these constructors, but the child classes do as they currently inherit directly.

Is there any way for me to do this:

```
class child3 : public common_call<base3>{
public:
    child3(param1, param2) : base3(param2) {/*do things here*/}
};
```

I'm trying to avoid making partial template specializations for each type of base if possible.

Comment: are you using c++11? In that case you could use variadic templates and perfect forwarding to add a constructor to `common_call`, which simply passes all arguments to the current base class.

Comment: If the implementation is irrelevant of the base class, then why not simply multiply inherit from `base` and `common_call` separately?

Comment: A few things I forgot to mention: The function foo() does not depend on the type of BASE so long as it derives from a common ancestor ANCESTOR (which base1, base2, and base3 do). The child classes on the other hand must derive from base1 etc. So I'm trying to avoid inheriting ANCESTOR twice.

Unfortunately, my environment doesn't permit C++11 yet. If it had, many of my problems would go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give `common_call` a templated constructor using variadic templates like this:

```
template <typename BASE>
class common_call : public BASE 
{
public:
    // C++11 variadic templates to define whole range of constructors
    template<typename... Args>
    common_call(Args&&... args)
    :
        BASE(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {}

    void foo() { /*implementation independent of base*/ }
};
```

you can then derive from `common_call` with any template argument (e.g. `base3`) and call whatever constructor that class has defined

```
class child3
:
    public common_call<base3>
{
public:
    child3(Type1 param1, Type2 param2)
    :
        common_call(param2), // call constructor overload with 1 parameter of Type2
        t1_(param1)          // initialize t1_ member
    {}

private:
    Type1 t1_;
};
```